# Setting an std::string variable value from gdb?

Tags: c++, string, debugging, gdb, stdstring

Is it possible... when the debugger is stopped at a breakpoint, to modify the value of a std::string variable without resorting to hacks like tweaking the memory image of the current buffer?

e.g. something like "set var mystring="hello world"

?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this (tested and works for me):

```
call mystring.assign("hello world")
```

The key is that instead of modifying memory directly, you call the object's functions to change its state. It so happens that `std::basic_string` has a member function called `assign` which does the job.

Comment: Excellent!  That's not only exactly what I need, it clarifies my thinking about how gdb works.

Comment: You can call the overloaded operators explicitly with `p mystring.operator=("hello world")` which is the verbose way of executing `mystring = "hello world"` and should work even when no other function overload exists.