# How to change the C++ string value in Eclipse Debugger?

Tags: c++, string, eclipse, debugging

While debugging a C++ program in Eclipse, I need to change the value of a string. But when I am about to do it, I see this and I cannot change it: 
(here's the link to the image, I don't have enough reputation yet) https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8gxu.png

What should I try? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `std::string` is actually not very simple behind the scenes. It has to manage a buffer of memory that your text is stored in. If you want the string to have a different (possibly much longer) value, then the `std::string` may have to deallocate the old buffer, allocate a new buffer of sufficient size and finally copy over the values, while keeping track of all the related information (e.g. its old and new size).

And then there's also [small string optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694302/what-are-the-mechanics-of-short-string-optimization-in-libc).

It's not trivial for a debugger to do these changes (without breaking the `std::string` in question). Some debuggers that understand the underlying compiler well (e.g. if you're working in Visual Studio) may be able to do this, but it's not a simple thing for a debugger to do.

Therefore, I would not be surprised if Eclipse's debugger does not allow changing string values at runtime. You might be able to change individual characters, but especially adding characters (or replacing with a longer string) might be beyond its capabilities.

<sup>Disclaimer: It's of course possible that there is a way or a workaround, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502314/setting-an-stdstring-variable-value-from-gdb) for gdb. I don't use Eclipse so I can't tell you, but if there is no way to do it then the above is essentially the reason for that.</sup>